# Sinch call reconnection Failed after switching mobile network

Tags: android, sinch

I am using Sinch SDK for app to app video calling for my android app. 
I am facing a problem when I am in a call and I am switching my mobile network (e.g WiFi to 4G or 4G to WiFi) sinch failed to reconnect the call.

Is there any solution for this? I am also tried by changing `MediaHandoverConfig` like below

```
MediaHandoverConfig mediaHandoverConfig = new MediaHandoverConfig(10,10000,10000,60000);
Beta.setMediaHandoverConfig(mSinchClient, mediaHandoverConfig);
```

But still facing the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a request on our support (support@sinch.com) informing your account details and callIds of your test calls, we have network handover as part of our standard test process and it works fine, but there are limitations, specially if the re-connect process takes too much time (>30secs), but that should not be your case, we need to investigate.

Br.
Sinch Voice & Video Team

Comment: Thanks for your reply I will try to communicate with since support team.